# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[D_8]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times M_2(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

> Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[D_8]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times M_2(\mathbb{Q})$

I want to prove that these $\mathbb{Q}$ algebras are isomorphic.
I understand why this holds for the corresponding $\mathbb{C}$ algebras. However I am dumbfounded as to how it works in the case of $\mathbb{Q}$.
One thing I can prove is that $D_8/[D_8,D_8]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. And from there I can prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2-1,y^2-1)$. But I don't know how to conntinue from here and if I can even use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathbb F$ is any field of characteristic zero, then $\mathbb F[D_8]$ is a direct sum of matrix algebras over division rings since by Maschke's theorem it is semisimple. Now as the OP points out
$$
D_8/[D_8,D_8] = D_8/Z(D_8)\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2=V_4
$$
where $V_4$ is called the "Klein 4-group", and it is easy to see that $\mathbb Q[V_4] \cong \mathbb Q^4$ (the isomorphism is just writing down all the 1-dimensional representations).

Now $Z(\mathbb Q[D_8])$ is $5$-dimensional, since $D_8$ has 5 conjugacy classes, and five irreducible representations, hence either $\mathbb Q[D_8]$ is either $\mathbb Q^4 \oplus \mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb Q)$ or $\mathbb Q[D_8] \cong \mathbb Q^4 \oplus D$ where $D$ is a $4$-dimensional noncommutative division algebra, and to decide which, you can just write down the two-dimensional representation $V$ and see what the image of $D_8$ spans inside $\text{End}(V)$: Indeed
$$
D_8 = \langle s,r\mid s^4=r^2=e, srs^{-1}=r^{-1}\rangle
$$
and the two-dimensional representation is given by
$$
r \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right); \quad s \mapsto  \left(\begin{array}{cc} -1 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{array}\right)
$$
(think of the symmetries of a square -- the matrix for $r$ is that of a rotation by $\pi/2$ with respect to any orthonormal basis, so pick one which is given by the eigenvectors of a reflection). It is then easy to see that $rs = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ (or geometrically, the two classes of reflections swap each others eigenlines) and so $\{1,r,s,rs\}$ is a basis of $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb Q)$.

Of course you don't even really need to calculate anything after you see that the image of $D_8$ lies in $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb Q)$, since the other option was a division algebra over $\mathbb Q$ of dimension $4$, but since everything can be worked out concretely with relatively little work, it seems better to be concrete.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand why the decomposition holds over $\mathbf{C}$, then all you need to know in this case is that $\mathbf{Q}$ is a splitting field for $\mathbf{Q}[D_8]$. This means every simple $\mathbf{Q}[D_8]$-module remains simple over $\mathbf{C}$ after extending scalars. Equivalently, $\text{End}(M) = \mathbf{Q}$ for any simple $\mathbf{Q}[D_8]$-module $M$. Hence the $D_i$'s in the Wedderburn-Artin decomposition of $\mathbf{Q}[D_8]$ are all $\mathbf{Q}$. For more info on splitting fields for algebras check out $\S 7$ of *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings* by Lam.

<s>Edit: I should add that one way we know $\mathbf{Q}$ is a splitting field is that all irreducible characters of $D_8$ are rational valued.</s>

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the last sentence, but it seems problematic: $\mathbb Q$ is a splitting field for $D_8$, but it is not a splitting field for $Q_8$, which has the same character table. (The Schur index for the two-dimensional representation of $Q_8$ over $\mathbb C$ is 2).

Comment: @krm2233 You are right! Having $K$-valued characters is a necessary but not sufficient condition for $K$ to be a splitting field. I was misremembering a result.

Answer (score 1):

Can you come up with  a multiplicative map from $D_8$ to each of the factors of the product on RHS ( with $1\mapsto 1$)?   If yes, then you get a multiplicative map from $D_8$ to RHS.  And from here you get a morphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ algebras

$$\mathbb{Q}[D_8] \to \mathbb{Q}^4 \times M_2(\mathbb{Q})$$

Now, $D_8= D_{2\times 4}$ is the group of symmetries of a regular $4$-gon ( i.e. a square). As such $D_8$ can be seen in different ways:

1. As a subgroup of $S_4$  ( since it permutes the $4$ vertices of a square).
2. As a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{Z}) \subset GL(2, \mathbb{R})$  ( those symmetries are linear maps of a simple form).

Now, from 1. and 2. we can get the $4$ morphism $D_8\to \mathbb{Q}^{\star}$ : (the signature of a permutation, and the determinant, will generate the $1$-dim characters).  As for the map from $D_8 \to M_2(\mathbb{Q})$, just write each element of $D_8$ as a matrix.

One still has to show that the map thus obtained is an isomorphism. Perhaps one could write down the inverse map ( the inverse Fourier transform).